# Find pdf of a multivariate function with log-normal distributions

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, lognormal-distribution

Consider the following function:

$f(x,t) = \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi(d_0+\alpha v) t}}\exp\left(-\dfrac{x^2}{4(d_0+\alpha v)t}-\lambda t\right)$

where the parameters $d_0,\alpha,\lambda$ are random variables.

Suppose that these random variables follow log-normal distributions:

$d_0 \sim \log \mathcal{N}(m_1,\sigma_1)$,
$\alpha \sim \log \mathcal{N}(m_2,\sigma_2)$ and
$\lambda \sim \log \mathcal{N}(m_3,\sigma_3)$.

How to find the probability density function of the function $f(x,t)$ ?

Comment: This has no closed-form analytical expression. Please, then, indicate more precisely *how* you would like to "find" the density function.  BTW, what is the reason for omitting $v$ (evidently some kind of a dispersion parameter) from the arguments of $f$?

Comment: The function $f(x,t)$ is the solution of the 1D parabolic equation $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial t}=-v\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+ D \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}-\lambda f$ with $D=d_0+\alpha *v$. The parameters $d_0,$ $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ are uncertained parameters. The purpose is to find the pdf of $f(x,t)$ knowing the pdf of the parameters when they follow a log-normal distribution.

Comment: Yes, that's clear.  But in what form do you need the pdf to be expressed?  You won't get it in a closed form, so you need to be more specific: some kind of infinite sum? An approximation? A Monte-Carlo simulation?

Comment: The ultimate goal is to find an analytical expression of the pdf of the solution $f(x,t)$ to obtain an analytical expression of its mean value and standard deviation, so as to link the uncertainties of the parameters to the evolution of the solution $f(x,t)$. In deed, this can be handle with a Monte-Carlo simulation, but since it's the simpliest case, we hoped to have an analytical form. Can you please give your arguments to justify that it is impossible to get it in a closed form ?

Comment: I'm basing these remarks on extensive experience in solving such equations and in working with combinations of lognormal distributions. Especially when sums of lognormals are involved, there is little hope of simplification; the other complications, such as taking roots of sums and exponentiating reciprocals of sums, are just more nails in that coffin.

Comment: Ok ! thank you, i see what you mean .. So let's forget the analytical approach and focuse on Monte-Carlo simulation !

Comment: Is it possible to find the pdf of f(x,t) using a Taylor expansion (around the mean values) of the random variables $d_0,\alpha$ and $\lambda$ ?

Comment: You might be able to approximate the distribution in various ways.  How well that works depends on the magnitudes of the $\sigma_i$: the smaller they are, the better off you'll be.  My sense is that they had better be small indeed--perhaps $0.15$ or smaller might be ok.  That's simply a guess, though.